# EntityFramework model building

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a class `Employee` that looks like the following:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Manager { get; set; }
}
```

I have another class `Manager` that extends this class and adds no other functionality:

```
public class Manager : Employee
{
}
```

In my `DbContext` derived class I have:

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
```

I want employee's with `Employee.Manager == 1` to be added to the `Managers` `DbSet` and the employee's with `Employee.Manager == 0` to be added to the `Employees` `DbSet`.

The database table is structured in this way and I need to be able to do something like this, because I have another class which has a foreign key to an employee and one to a manager.

How can I accomplish this or is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: In other words, you are using Table Per Hierarchy, and the `Manager` value is your Discriminator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order For Code First to use your custom discriminator column, you must modify the default behavior using the Fluent API.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .Map(e => e.Requires("Manager").HasValue(0))
        .Map<Manager>(m => m.Requires("Manager").HasValue(1));

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

A couple things to note:

- There is only one `DbSet<Employee>` in this scenario.  A `DbSet<Manager>` **will not work**. An `Employee` retrieved from the database can be identified as a manager by checking the `Manager` value, and a `var manager = new Manager()` will automatically be assigned the correct discriminator.
- **ALL** types which inherit from `Employee` must be given a value for the Discriminator in this `modelBuilder`.  If you skip an inherited class, you will receive runtime errors when accessing any class in the hierarchy.